# Display text after clicking on a date in CalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendarview

Is there a code to display text after clicking on a specific date in `Calendarview`?

For example, I have created a `TextView` below the calendar to display a text after clicking on a certain date, but am unsure of how to make the text show up after clicking on a specific date in the calendar view. The text that would display would also have to be typed in myself as it has to be specific to different dates.

Comment: Use [`CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#setOnDateChangeListener(android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener)).

Answer (score 0):

When you click on specific date of Calendarview that date show in your textview

```
    CalendarView calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            textView.setText(month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question but thank you for the reply